# ImageView, why different size?

Tags: java, android

First thing, I know many people have asked same thing, but this one is nearly same but I have few more questions.

I have an image of 48px x 48px, so if I set this image in ImageView with

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

then image looks bigger but if I use following fixed size, it gets smaller

```
layout_width="48dp"
layout_height="48dp"
```

I think it's now showing properly(not pixelated ?) with 48dp, but why it got bigger if I use wrap_content ? And if the image size through wrap_content is correct then whats the point of using dp(if it make image smaller) ?

Comment: how you setting the image to the imageView ?

Comment: `dp` is not the same as `px` by the way

Comment: You might be setting the background as the image source that might be the reason it is getting stretched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/seprator2"
    layout_width="48dp"
    layout_height="48dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

And if still it shows small then your image must contains alpha around it.

Answer (score 6):

`48dp` (or `48dip`) stands for "Density Independent Pixel". This means that the physical size of the image as displayed on the screen of an Android should be the same regardless of screen density and size. In order to support this, Android adjusts the actual pixel size displayed based on screen density. Your findings of different sizes will vary from device to device.

The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is: `pixels = dps * (density / 160)`. For example, on 240 dpi screen, `1dp` would equal 1.5 physical pixels. Using dp units to define your application’s UI is highly recommended, as a way of ensuring proper display of your UI on different screens.

Answer (score 3):

This probably happens because you don't explicitly set the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). Set your scaleType in XML as follows and you should be fine:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: Yes, it needed scaleType. I used scaleType="fitXY".
Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted using the empty checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is larger than the view, then you could scale it using:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```